# How to read formatted string from a text file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a txt file which has data in the below format:

```
int string string
int string string
int string string
.
.
.
.
int string string
```

i need to read the file line by line and save the data into respective arrays.
It has to be done in ObjectiveC...

```
outputString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

I've tried the code above but this gives all the contents of the file into one NSString. Also if i use `[outputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];` I'm only going to get an array with the lines separated out.

Comment: `outputString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];`

Comment: Sounds like homework, looks like homework...

Comment: `outputString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];`<br /> I've done this but this gives all the contents of the file into one NSString. <br /> Also if i use [outputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; I'm only going to get an array with the lines separated out ..

Comment: Unless you know how long the strings are, or how they are delimited, you really can't extract them individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so this is how I did it ... I just used the fact that ObjC is a superset of C

```
char personName[256];
char imgFilename[512];
int personNumber;

NSArray *array = [outputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; 
int lines = [array count];
FILE *file = fopen([filePath UTF8String],"r");
for (int i = 0; i<lines; i++) {
    fscanf(file,"%d %s %s",&personNumber, personName, imgFilename);
    NSLog(@"From Fscanf %d %s %s",personNumber,personName,imgFilename);
}
fclose(file);
```